# Can i track my friend's iphone with the help of any app on iphone?

Tags: iphone, gps

Can i track my friend's iphone with the help of any app on iphone? Is it really possible? He always tells a lie about location.

I tried many apps on App Store but they all are fake.

Comment: So you want an application on your iPhone that shows the location of your friends iPhone?  Without them knowing?

Comment: @robzolkos - Yes

Comment: I have looked and looked there is a way to track your own phone but not other peoples.

Comment: Tracking someone else's phone without their permission is unambiguously unethical. It's just the kind of tool that would make life easier for stalkers and thieves. I'm not saying you are either a stalker or a thief but that building and deploying such an app has serious implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this application](http://petewarden.github.com/iPhoneTracker/).
It uses an hidden file stored on the iPhone recording an history of location. It has been a little buzz [since yesterday](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/TECH/mobile/04/20/iphone.tracking/index.html) when it came out on almost all media worldwide.
From the description of how to tool is working, it will even work with a backup file of the device. So you can use it on a Mac where the iPhone has been sync'ed and backed-up.

*PS:*
*I don't want to go in the discusion "is it a good thing to track people etc...". Just trying to answer the OP question...*

---

*edit*
Now available for windows on [this link](http://www.raphaelabitbol.info/iphonetracker/).

Comment: How to install this app on my iphone or Windows 7 PC? I don't use MAC.

Comment: The application is developed in Objective-C and is then design to natively run on Mac. However, as the source code has been open-sourced, it may well be that the project will be ported to Windows in a near future.

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas Added a link to a tool for Windows.

Comment: Be aware that an encrypted backup stops this vector

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Google Latitude on the phone?

Comment: Does Latitude give the possibility to get an history of movement for a given person?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about the free [Find my Friends](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/find-my-friends/id466122094?mt=8) app? It's free, made by Apple (so definitly not fake) and works on iOS 5 (which your iPhone 4 supports)

Answer (score 0):

Tracking someone else’s phone with their permission: Use http://www.3nus.com/locator, no need to install anything, just enter the other side phone number and send him link in SMS, all he has to do it click on the link, and you'll get his location.